# Need query to pass list to stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I am new to sql server and need help to creating a query to insert all data into table in one call using stored procedure.
For example I have 1 User(say "Tech" has Id 1) and list of Customers("C#","ASP","MVC").
My Table structure 
Id (PK),
UserId(FK)
Customers varchar.

Accepted result like
UserId----|-----Customers
1      ----------|----- C#
1   ----------|----- ASP
1   ----------|----- MVC

I will pass userId and list of customers to my SP.

Comment: ...and what did you try?

Comment: What is your question, you just told us your requirements, you have not stated what the problem you are having implementing this by yourself.

Comment: question is how to iterate over list in query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is as follows . I am assuming that you have input like this format   @userId=1 , @ListOfSubjects ='asp,c#' ..
here is the sample proc . The idea is to first convert list od comma seprated string ofsubject to table and then insert it . To do that I created a sample UDF which will retun a table when comma separated string is passed to it .

```
        create proc SampleUser_Insert 
         @UserId int , 
        @ListOfSubjects varchar(1000)
        as
        begin

             --set @UserId=1
             --set @ListOfSubjects ='asp,c#,mvc'


             declare @sampleTable table (userId int, subjects varchar(100))

             insert into    @sampleTable (userId,subjects )

             SELECT @userId, data FROM dbo.[SplitString](@ListOfSubjects, ',')
             select * from @sampleTable

        end

    --  exec SampleUser_Insert 1,'a,b,c'
```

the udf is as follows

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (
        @String NVARCHAR(4000),
        @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN
    (
        WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
        AS(
            SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
            UNION ALL
            SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
                FROM Split
                WHERE endpos > 0
        )
        SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
            'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
        FROM Split
    )
    GO
```

Comment: Thanks @Yashveer Singh

Comment: @Kida welcome happy coding